# ASP.NET Maintaining Search History in an application

Tags: asp.net

Recently i received an interview question.

How to maintain search day to day search history in an asp.net application?

Which one of the below would be the right choice?

```
1)Cookies 2) Sql Server 3) Session State
```

I guess the correct option could be Cookies.Please kindly share your thought.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL Server is the most reliable way of maintaining whatever. Cookies cannot generally be relied upon, and sessions expire and lose all data.

So the question boils down to: if you need to mainain long-term historical records, go with SQL Server. If you want to show what a particular user has searched for, go for session (or cookies, but they're somewhat size-limited).

Answer (score 0):

All 3 options are acceptable in different scenarios for many different reasons - it's a softener question designed to get you thinking and talking:

(1) Cookies - for a per user / browser session provides a client-side solution (provided the user accepts / does not delete them) and you don't care that this can happen. However, this does tie the user to the browser. Useful for anonymous per-user browsing but not if your intention is to keep or query the history.

(2) SQL - guarantees history is saved server side but you would need a mechanism such as a client login to associate the history with the user and the only solution of the 3 presented that would allow you to perform any sort of historical multi-user analysis / analytics.

(3) Session state - not advisable - but arguably similar to cookies but without the caveat that cookie acceptance is required - however you introduce the timeout issue and again tie the user to the browser and limited lifetime of the information.